# Changing delimiter used by jmeter to save results as CSV

Tags: jmeter

I have a Jmeter script which will fire some HTTP requests. From the requests i am getting the required values to my output.
In the jmeter.properties file i have mentioned as follow:

```
# For use with Comma-separated value (CSV) files or other formats
# where the fields' values are separated by specified delimiters
# Default:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=|
# For TAB, since JMeter 2.3 one can use:
#jmeter.save.save-service.default_delimiter=\t
```

But it is not reflecting in my output.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I've added to the jmeter.properties file the following lines:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv 
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=;
csvread.delimiter=;
```

Now Simple Data Writer saves results using ; to separate fields' values. But when I save data in the Aggregate Report element (by clicking the 'Save Table Data' button) the values in result aggregate.csv file are separated by ,

Answer (score 0):

If you really did what you are describing in the code excerpt, then you forgot to uncomment fields by removing # before the concerned line.

Furthermore you are making a mistake in the property names, they should be:

- jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=|
- jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t

For full reference, see [jmeter.properties](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/tags/v2_7/bin/jmeter.properties).

But I am not sure to answer your question , as it is not clear though, can you clarify it.

Regards

Philippe M.